# Working modular example for JavaFx8 + OSGi + Gradle multiproject without additional tooling?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, javafx, osgi, equinox

I am stuck with a problem I can't solve for weaks now.

I have to create a modular JavaFX application, where each component defines a "domain unit" (with models+views+controllers). Each component can be loaded into a "shell application" (as a content of a tab view or multiple tab views) and the modules can depend on another module(s) (their content in tabs won't appear if their dependency is not loaded).

That's why I was planning to create an **OSGi** based **JavaFX** application and build it with **Gradle** as a multiproject.

I've already tried dozens of tutorials with no success and I experienced, that most of these tutorials:

- are outdated, not reproducible (e.g. elcipse's interface, templates have changed, bndtools tutorials doesn't seem to work, equinox doesn't seem to to work without felix, javafx8+osgi generate different kind of problems... etc.)
- are too complex for a beginner (I just started to learn OSGi and Gradle) and they skip important steps I am not aware of
- contain too much "IDE magic" (I would rather type some code instead of filling forms in eclipse)
- some solve the problem with different tools (maven/tycho, bndtools, e(fx)clipse), but I've got no time to learn them

I want my application to be independent from IDE's environment. I **don't** want to use e(fx)clipse or BndTools if possible (even if they can make the build process easier)..
I'm experimenting with OSGi implementations, that's why I would rather not to choose between Equinox, Felix or Karaf.
I've already programmed similar application in .NET world, but it seems to me impossible to do the same in Java world..

My main questions are:

- is it possible to do what I have imagined?
- how to create a gradle multiproject what is IDE/platform independent (if projects are not tied to eclipse environment, or equinox, but it's possible to use them)?
- what are the best ways to initialize the application (shell application + modules) and load the independent modules/bundles/components?
- how to separate my views into subprojects (what build.gradle files should contain)?
- how to solve the javafx8 inpompatibility with osgi?
- what is the correct way to apply javafx plugin in gradle?
- what tutorials are the most relevant?
- is there any working example, pattern or tutorial (without using additional tools) what solve the same problem (using only osgi+javafx+gradle)?

Comment: I fully support you wanting your application to be independent from IDEs. But why does that mean you don't want to use Bndtools? It's just a tool, your application will not depend on it. If you are having problems with Bndtools tutorial then please let us know... just saying they "don't work" doesn't help us to fix them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I could group your questions in differents topic:

**OSGI**

You just need to google around to find out that is a java specification that encourages modularization, provides hot-deploy feature, and so on. As I told you, is just an specification like Java Servlet API, so they are different providers or implementers of OSGI Specification such as Felix and Equinox. Karaf instead is a OSGI container based on Felix, so you get all felix benefits and in addiction karaf natives features. For that reason I encourage you to take Karaf into use.

**Aquote BndTool**

In order to satisfy the OSGI specification, you need that your modules contains a MANIFEST.MF which holds all dependency information so Karaf create the classloader required for your bundles.
Assuming that you don't want to create that MANIFEST.MF files by hand, you could take aqute/bndtool for that. Don't get mess with bndtool for eclipse plugin. That application can be used from command line, from a maven plugin, or from a gradle plugin. Basically scans your classes, check the imports, and create a MANIFEST.MF automatically.

**Gradle**

If you choose gradle as a build tool, then you can take into use: [Bnd Gradle plugin](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle/README.md#gradle-plugin-for-workspace-builds). It's easy to set up, but follow the instruction for non-workspace plugin. If you don't want to use BndTool for eclipse. IDE independent solution, you mentioned in your question.

**MultiProject Layout**

How the project layout should look like, depends on your modularization, but you can have a look on this layout example that uses gradle+osgi+karaf for a multiproject. Perhaps inspires you.

https://github.com/antoniomaria/gradle-karaf-bnd-project